# Reading fingerprint input in python

Tags: python, django, fingerprint, biometrics

I have a java application for fingerprint enrollment which works well using digitalPersona SDK.

I however need to authenticate using the enrolled images in a web app I'm developing with django. I believe this should mean that the django app is able to read the fingerprint image from the scanner to compare with existing data. Is there a python library I can use to read the input?

I have checked discussions on OpenCV forum but they seem to be focused on the comparison/verification of the image and not reading the image from the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an RPi, there are many tutorials, but I assume you aren't using that.

You might want to take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icniGw3Euq4